# How to add browser file or image button in Tinymce

Tags: php, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have written below code in my php file. I got image option but to upload image I need to add URL

```
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "exact",
        elements : "descp",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

});
```

I  am not getting browse file option on execution

Answer (score 0):

You  can use external plugins  for image/media upload to tinymce. openmanager is one of working plugin for image/media upload.

Try this
https://github.com/rmorse/Open-Manager

Answer (score -1):

Add these arguments with others

```
    tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
    file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {

   // Provide image and alt text for the image dialog
   if (meta.filetype == 'image') {
     callback('myimage.jpg', {alt: 'My alt text'});
   }


  }
 });
```

Comment: still not getting browse button